# Why isnt firestore filtering and always returning all documents?

Tags: javascript, angular, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I have the following code and it always retrieves all documents, as if the filter is not being applied.
Using angular@5.2.0 and angularfire2@5.0.0-rc.6

```
loads$: Observable<Load[]>;
status$: BehaviorSubject<string|null>;

this.loads$ = this.status$.switchMap(status => 
    afs.collection<Load>('loads', ref => {
       let query : firebase.firestore.Query = ref;
       query.where('status', '==', status);
       return query;
    }).valueChanges());
});
```

The database is setup this way
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vOyjL.png

I update the status observable via:

```
 filterByStatus(status: string) {
    this.status$.next(status); 
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this code sitting inside a subscription. All I did was moved it over to the component constructor and it started working. Found out I can use  combineLatest() to do what I wanted to do.

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue, fix it by replacing line `query.where('status', '==', status);` by `query = query.where('status', '==', status);`